# Configuring Free SSL certificate on IIS in EC-2 Instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis, amazon-ec2

I have hosted my PHP MySQL web application on EC-2 on windows 2019 on free tier. I have assigned the elastic IP to the instance and pointed to the our domain which is hosted on third party. Now i would like to enable the Free SSL certificate by amazon certificate manager and i have created that. I am little bit confused in the next steps can anyone help me there.

1. Do i need to use Amazon Route 53 service for this? Is this service
   is available in free tier?
2. Or Just Elastic load balancer is the only one i need to set up in the
   further process?

Can anyone advise me here and it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a free SSL from the certificate manager you will need to apply the SSL to one of either:

- CloudFront
- Elastic Load Balancer

If you don't want to use either of these then take a look at [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/windows-other).

Comment: Do I need to use Route 53 along with the Elastic Load Balancer?

Comment: The SSL is bound to the ELB, Route 53 is simply Amazons Domain Service :)

Comment: When i am referring to few tutorials, In that creating an hosted zone in route 53 with the domain name and updating these name server into the third party domain portal also, so i am little confused here, this step is really mandatory to follow or i can just set up with ELB only?

Comment: If you want free SSL, it is bound to the ELB. You can use whichever hosting you want with to resolve your hostname to the ELB.